The meaning of "melt through something"
In the phrase: "a situation in which the nuclear fuel becomes too hot and melts through its container"
What is the meaning of "melts through its container"?
In my opinion, It seems that in this phrase "melts through its container" means that it becomes liquid and comes out of its container, but I couldn't find this meaning of "melt" in dictionaries.
The meaning of "melt" in the Cambridge Dictionary: to turn from something solid into something soft or liquid, or to cause something to do this

Isn't it the container that melts, because the fuel is so hot (which might also be molten)?

Yes, 'melt', like (e.g. 'burn') can be used that way: a very hot thing can melt through, or burn through, something else. The dictionary actually says '(become soft or liquid) or to cause something to do this'. The white-hot nuclear fuel causes the steel or concrete container to become soft and so it can sink through into the ground. Such a worst-case calamity has been called (in the USA) the 'China syndrome' because the fuel is imagined to melt all the way to China, on the other side of the Earth. Of course it wouldn't do that.

to bite through something; to melt through something, to sail through something, etc. etc.

The sentence means that the heat from the nuclear fuel is causing the container to melt, allowing the fuel to escape. The nuclear fuel itself may or may not be a solid, but the phrasing indicates that it is turning the normally solid container into a liquid. To "melt through" something uses the second definition you quote, meaning to cause something else to turn from solid to liquid.
If a hot knife melts, the knife itself is turning into liquid.
If a hot knife melts (through) butter, it is turning the butter into liquid.
There is another meaning you might encounter for to "melt through" something, to indicate that the resulting liquid has passed through a container that otherwise would have held a solid. Like if you are carrying ice in a backpack and find your back getting wet, you might say the ice has "melted through the bag".
The context should indicate whether the speaker is talking about something so hot as to melt the container, or whether it escaped the intact container simply by becoming liquid. Both interpretations are possible, but in this instance, it is the fuel melting its container, not the fuel spilling simply because it turned to liquid.

Here, the through specifies that the full thickness of the container’s wall is melted, from the inside all the way to the outside. This is analogous to the distinction in armor mechanics between penetration, which means any passing some nonzero distance into a plate’s thickness, and perforation, which means penetrating all the way through the plate’s full thickness.

melt here works the same as something breaks through its container. It''s the container that melts / breaks.
